# AS3 Should I be using classes for these functions I made?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, mouseevent, instantiation, stage

I'm a bit confused as to whether or not to be using classes to the general interface of a game I'm making.

I made an inventory system (this includes putting items in your inventory, combining them, using them, activating them, having the inventory sort itself, a way to examine the items in a zoomed mode, etc) which works with the class "item".

http://evadiendome.com/game.swf

and a movement system (just a normal pathfinder that reacts to mouse clicks with the main character and that will eventually be modified to affect any character in case I need to script cutscenes).

http://evadiendome.com/pathfinder.swf

Currently the only class I'm using is "item", to define items. But all the rest is in the time line.
I'm meaning to merge both the pathfinder and the inventory system into one now that they are both finished. And I was wondering how should I go about this.

At first I thought I'd just shove them into the action window. But this seems really sloppy.
So then I thought I'd define each system as a class, instance them once, and use them normally. I tried doing this but it's sprouting errors everywhere.
It doesn't recognize the stage, mouseX, mouseY. And even if I get rid of "stage" the listeners won't get recognized.

I did some reading and saw I needed to pass the "stage" as a parameter in the constructor.
And I'm not sure if it will work, but I added "e.currentTarget." In front of mouseX and mouseY in order from errors to stop popping.
But then I extended the main class to EventDispatcher in order for it to work...

and that just felt wrong and realized I was in way over my head and just patching patches.

I've been also getting some errors saying the class can't be instantiated in the main file.
I've been able to work around this by calling it in a different way. But I'm really not sure which is the proper one.

--

So that's when I started wondering.
Should I really turn my two systems into classes?
It feels like I'm reworking them and patching them in order to do something which might not even be needed or optimal.

But if this was the best way, I'd love some input on how to fix these errors properly.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It's really hard to give you good advice without seeing your code. However, you may want to look at the code posted here http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2010/04/sample-code-for-oop-timeline-insideria.html that was posted as a companion to this article http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html . Note that if you're instantiating objects by adding them on the timeline, you _can't_ use constructor arguments.

Comment: I'll take a look at those articles as soon as I get home, thanks! Well, the code is pretty long to paste it here, but basically it boils down to eventListeners looking for mouseDown and mouseDown to determine whether you're clicking or dragging, and how they react to target :Item based on where it's instantiated (if an item is in the stage it will pick it up, if its in the inventory instance it will describe it, but if its there and you drag it it will go with your mouse). That'd be the inventory system.

For the pathfinder it just creates and examines :Nodes in a 2D array and returns results.

Comment: Although the pathfinder then uses those results (generally generated by mouseX and mouseY) to move an instanced :Character through them

Comment: What gave you the idea you needed to add a reference to the stage in the constructor, and how are you instantiating the Classes you're passing that reference to?